# What code would would convert sequence of listNode objects into another sequence

Tags: c#, linked-list

Using C#, I need to convert this sequence of ListNodes:

```
list -> [1] -> [2] -> [3]/
temp -> [4] -> [5] -> [6]/
```

Into:

```
list -> [5] -> [3] -> [4] -> [2]
```

I've tried doing a mylist.AddLast() and adding and removing the values like that but don't really know how to go about it.

```
static public void Main()
    {

        LinkedList<string> my_list = new LinkedList<string>();

        // Adding elements in the LinkedList
        // Using AddLast() method
        my_list.AddLast("[1]");
        my_list.AddLast("[2]");
        my_list.AddLast("[3]");
        my_list.Remove("[1]"); 
        my_list.Remove("[2]"); 
        my_list.AddLast("[5]")
        my_list.AddLast("[4]")
```

The list is not coming out in the order that it should be.

Comment: missing `;` at last 2 statements

Comment: it work's ,output will `[3]->[5]->[4]` which as per your input in code. what you want?

Comment: `list -> [5] -> [3] -> [4] -> [2]` for this see [demo](https://rextester.com/GPCO80629)